# Pythonic custom sort for letter grades 'D', 'C-' ,..., 'A+'?

Tags: python, string, sorting, idioms

Is there a more Pythonic, compact, intuitive way to sort letter-grades than this (without using a custom dict)?

```
grades = ['B-','C','B','C+','A','D+','B+','C-','A+','D','A-']

sorted(grades, key=lambda g: (g[0], '+ -'.index((g+' ')[1])) )

['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D']
```

In order to get the comparative numerical order of 'X-','X','X+', I do a hacky append of a space ' ' so that `g[1]` always exists, so then I can use `.index()` to get the rank of the modifier '+ -'.

(Motivated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766829/pandas-ordered-categorical-data-on-exam-grades-d-a/))

Comment: More intuitive will probably mean less compact. Which one do you care about?

Comment: @abamert, ok show me both a more intuitive, and a more compact (but not taken to golf extremes).

Comment: Actually… you have a fixed set of 11 values. Why wouldn't a dict be more intuitive? `gradedict = {grade: i for i, grade in enumerate('A+ A A- B+ B B- C+ C C- D+ D'.split())}` could well be useful in more places than one, and then it's just `sorted(grades, key=gradedict.get)`.

Comment: I guess if we were going to do a lot of sorting or keying on the grade column, we would just augment single-letter grades ('C') with space afterwards. But then if we were going to go that far, easier to just use a dict to translate 'A':90, 'B+':85 etc.. Essentially like a pandas or R Categorical

Comment: Another advantage of a static dict is that if you start getting unexpected grades, it can raise an exception instead of silently treating `S` as worse than `D` instead of better than `A+`, or `a` as worse than `D` instead of equal to `A`, etc. (Although since I used `get` instead of `__getitem__`, the error will probably be pretty cryptic instead of useful, so maybe don't do that…)

Comment: Also, it'll probably be faster (which probably doesn't matter in your program, but people who are looking to save 3 keystrokes at the expense of readability are often willing to spend those 3 keystrokes to save 20ns, so…)

Comment: To the downvoters, if you have any constructive criticism of the question let us know. This topic gets many questions so I was curious to have a canonical on sorting. Can it be improved further?

Answer (score 4):

No.

```
modmap = {
  '-': 0,
  '': 1,
  '+': 2
}

print(sorted(grades, key=lambda x: (-ord(x[0]), modmap[x[1:]])))
```

Comment: It works, but loses legibility. Maybe I should embrace the dict approach.

Comment: This sorts backwards. Forwards would not only match what the question asked for, but would also be simpler (no need for `-ord`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes-ish?

```
>>> sorted(grades, key=lambda g: g + ',')
['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D']
```

Clearly more compact, and I'd say also pythonic, just not very intuitive :-P

Works because `'+' < ',' < '-'`.

---

Another one:

```
>>> sorted(grades, key=lambda g: (g[0], ' -'.find(g[1:])))
['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D']
```

Suffix `+` won't be found in `' -'`, so `find` returns `-1`. Empty suffix results in `0`, and suffix `-` results in `1`.

Comment: That's quite a neat trick, as long as you comment exactly how it works: because the ASCII values happen to be ordered like 43 '+' 44 ',' 45 '-' (the numbers don't matter, just the relative ordering, and that there's a character ',' in-between). If '+' and '-' were adjacent you couldn't get away with it.

Comment: So in this particular case the ASCII code numbers conveniently work just like my more verbose `'+ -'.index(...)`

Comment: @smci Well, I don't think the exact numbers matter, I'd say what matters is the `'+' < ',' < '-'` that I mentioned.

Comment: @smci Although yes, I knew some "pairs" of characters are separated in ASCII, and the way I found `','` was to do `ord('+')`, `ord('-')`, and then `chr(44)`.

Comment: ...or look at the [ASCII chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). I wouldn't rely on numerical coincidences with [extended character sets like latin1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) or utf8 or Unicode though...

Comment: ...the ASCII codes for mathematical operators are out-of-order

Comment: @smci Yeah, I think I actually googled ascii first but then couldn't bother to pick a result and search the characters, so switched to that Python way instead. What do you mean with "rely on"? I mean, I wouldn't rely on *my intuition*, but after looking them up, I think we can rely on what I used there.

Comment: By "rely on" I mean that in Unicode there are multiple plus and minus signs, also their ordering won't be intuitive (and there may be more added in future Unicode revisions), so you can't do this trick.

Comment: @smci Ah, yeah, if other plus or minus signs are allowed as well, that's a different game.

Comment: @smci If other plus/minus signs are allowed, I guess yours might be the most compact, just list them all in your string. Maybe `index(g[1:] or ' '))` would be slightly clearer, and `find` would be slightly shorter.

Comment: @smci Just added another solution, and that one can be generalized by including all different minus signs in the string.